# Rails 4 - Associations and date comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, nested, associations

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have models for project, project_dates and profile.  The associations are:

Profile.rb

```
has_many :projects
```

Project.rb

```
belongs_to :profile
has_one :project_date
accepts_nested attributes for :project_date
```

Project_dates.rb

```
belongs_to :project
```

In my profile show page, I am trying to show each project and to identify whether it is currently open for expressions of interest.  I have an attribute in my project_dates table called :eoi.

I have white labelled my project_dates attributes in each of the projects controller and the project dates controller and I have created a build method in the new action of the project controller (for build project_date)

In the profile show page, I have:

```
<% Profile.find(params[:id]).projects.sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <% group.compact.each do |project| %>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="well">
                                            <div class="indexdisplay">
                                                <%= image_tag project.hero_image_url, width: '80px', height: '80px' if project.hero_image.present? %>
                                                <br><span class="indexheading"> <%= link_to project.title, project %> </span>
                                                <% if project.project_date.eoi > Date.today %>
                                                    open
                                                <% end %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                    <% end %>
                            <% end %>
```

When I save this and try it, I get an error message that says:

```
undefined method `eoi' for nil:NilClass
```

I can see in the logs, that the form inputs are being inserted as part of the post:

```
INSERT INTO "project_dates" ("recurring_project", "frequency", "start_date", "completion_date", "eoi", "project_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["recurring_project", "t"], ["frequency", "Each semester"], ["start_date", "2016-03-05"], ["completion_date", "2016-06-05"], ["eoi", "2016-09-05"], ["project_id", 25], ["created_at", "2016-02-05 01:46:18.675074"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-05 01:46:18.675074"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

I can't understand why this isn't working. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

When I try:

```
<% = @project.project_date.eoi %>
```

in the projects show page - it works.

When I try <% = project.project_date.eoi %> inside the projects display in the profile show page, I get an error which says:

```
undefined method `eoi' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Check your db, any `project` is missing `project_date`?

Comment: What do you mean? I can see in the server logs that the project dates are part of the post. I'm not sure what you're suggesting that I check.

Comment: I meant maybe exist a project which doesn't have project_date, just check `a = Project.count`, `b = Project.joins(:project_date).count`, if `a > b` is the problem I want to talk about!